# Rails error when adding route /events/browse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The error I keep getting is:

```
(Object too large. Modify ActionDispatch::Request::Session#inspect or adjust BetterErrors.maximum_variable_inspect_size if you need to see it.)
```

I've added the route:

```
get  '/events/browse',  to: 'events#browse'
```

and have a page called `browse.html.erb` in my events model. I'm fairly new to Rails so hope this isn't too silly of a question.

So far, I've added gem '`binding_of_caller`' as was suggested in my error log, ran `bundle install` to update the gem file and tried turning the server on and off. I have not tried much more besides googling the error as I've been doing the paths the same way in my other apps and have not had this error yet.

Additional info: when directed to this route the user is logged in... not sure if that has something to do with it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: General advice: Adding relevant code snippets improves chances people answer your question and those answers being as detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For one the error has something to do with the better errors gem. 
But I would suggest your routes change. It is looking for the following because of the `/`'s

```
/controllers
  /events
    /browse
      -events_controller.rb
```

I would change the route to be:

```
resources :events do, only: [] do
  get :browse, on: :member
end
```

You can add any of the crud actions to the only array as needed. The on member will ensure that the browse action requires an event_id, `/events/event_id/browse`. If you're trying for an index of events to browse, you can use `on: :collection`. That will give you a route of `/events/browse` [Rails Routes Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Thank you - I ended up using the :member and that fixed the issue